# Trying to build a procedure to create a variable but it gets trapped inside

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, ms-access

I need to count the lines in a certain table of an Access database a lot, but the current code I'm using locks that variable inside brackets, and it doesn't exist outside of them, which is making turning the calling of the `count` variable through a procedure a bit. Well, it's not working. Removing the brackets just breaks the syntax, and it gives me errors of internal variables not existing (which, why it says that, I have no idea. They do, they've been created, and they work fine with the brackets in place.)

This is the code I've been using, and I just do what I need to do inside the brackets:

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=access.mdb";
conn.Open();
OleDbCommand cmmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM probe", conn);

using (OleDbDataReader myReader = cmmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Load(myReader);
    int count = dt.Rows.Count;
    lblCount.Text = count.ToString();
    conn.Close();
}
```

Making that a procedure gets me that `count` variable, but then locks it away, completely unusable... not sure how to set it free.

Comment: Define the variable outside the scope of the `using` statement. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132(v=vs.71).aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Put the count variable declaration in the outer function scope.

```
              private int GetCount()
              {
                int count;
                OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
                conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=access.mdb";
                conn.Open();
                OleDbCommand cmmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM probe", conn);
                using (OleDbDataReader myReader = cmmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    dt.Load(myReader);
                    count = dt.Rows.Count;
                    lblCount.Text = count.ToString();
                    conn.Close();

                }
                return count;
              }

              int myCount = GetCount();
```

Comment: Beat me to it :) Not sure function-scope counts as *global* but I get the idea.

Comment: Yes, it's true. I have made an update to make it clear.

Comment: I tried it and it allows it, but when I call the procedure, and try to use count, it tells me that it doesn't exist. I'm going to try creating count just before the calling of the procedure? I'm not sure that will work though.

Comment: Where are you trying to use the count from? The caller of this function?

Comment: Yeah. I want to call the count and then take further action based on the result of the count. I tried creating the int count before the procedure call, but it makes me define it, and then the COUNT procedure doesn't change it. It seems that what happens in the brackets, still stays in the backets, even if the variable exists outside it.

Comment: If you need it outside of the function you can consider returning it. See my updated code.